# Are you only able to have no more than 2 or 3 tag edits pending?

Tags: support, tags, editing, suggested-edits

I have submitted a couple of edits to tags only to find there were some boiler-plate languages previously used which I then tried to incorporate in my previous edits as well as submit new ones in topics that I used in the past.

Previously all of them approved in short order, I got to do more of these. However, after submitting edits to two or maybe three tags (to the guidance and/or the details of them) apparently still pending (for e.g. the [U.S Constitution tag](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/us-constitution/info) improvement of my own improvement previously approved), and now the "improve tag" button on other tags no longer actually allow any edit either to the usage guidance or the detailed description of any more tags.

My gut tells me there may be some restrictions in the number of these edits which may be submitted by those not having the tag-edit privilege without approval. But I'm also slightly concerned that I was singled out and not on the basis of a reasonable requirement that one do a good faith effort in their edits, and have a reasonable expectation that they could give a description that improves the tag and not worsens it.

These criteria, I imagine what may govern, if ever, the proceeding to decide whether to suspend someone's privilege to make wiki improvements to tags other than, for e.g., on the automatic basis of not allowing more than a few edits at the same time by those not having the edit-approval privilege too.

I wanted to standardize the usage guidance language of my other two tag edits to the European Union and the European Convention on Human Rights; however, it is blocked as described above.

So, I guess, I'd like to know why it is currently not possible for me to submit improvements, including to my own tag wiki improvements previously submitted and accepted? Is there a limit of how many may be pending, or was it made for any unrelated reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've reached the maximum of five pending suggesting edits. They are sat in the Review Queue waiting to be, er, reviewed.

See the accepted answer for [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/906208) under **Editing** and the accepted answer for [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/906208)