# Can my tag-edit privilege be unblocked or a reason given for why it is suspended?

Tags: support, tags, editing, suggested-edits

This question is a continuing inquiry rising out of the the question: [Are you only able to have no more than 2 or 3 tag edits pending?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/are-you-only-able-to-have-no-more-than-2-or-3-tag-edits-pending)

@Rick's answer indicated that my presumably 5 tag edits are being, er, reviewed.

But, er, it's getting closer to a week, and I find it highly unlikely that my edits are still sitting in the review queue as, by now, they either would have been approved (like each of those submitted before my privilege has clearly been suspended) or they, strangely, would have been rejected each (5), but in no case is it remotely possible that not even a single one would have been decided one way or another to reenable tag edits.

Yet, my tag edit privilege is suspended.

I would appreciate at this point if the mods could take of any bans they put on it.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you've been banned, I've just looked at your [us- constitution] tag edit and it's still waiting for a second review. I'm not sure why it hasn't been picked up, maybe not everyone with Review Queue privileges can see it..?

Comment: I’m gonna give the wild guess you did the first review so thank you for that — regardless ifpositive or negative. Would be great if any mods could address the question you raised whether the edits are visible to everyone with Review Queue privileges

Answer (score 1):

### Apparently we had not enough people checking [the edit queue](https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) in the last week

According to [your log](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/36359/kisspuska?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you made 12 Edits on Sept. 16th, some of which I had seen in the approval queue today. At the time of writing, those appear to be "approved"